# Ansible connection to AKS cluster

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, azure-aks

I have an aks cluster created in Azure protal and now I want to manage the cluster using few playbooks (eg: create namespace, list pods) Unable to run the playbook as it couldn't figure out the kubeconfig location specified and throws error: *fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to load kubeconfig due to load() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Loader'"}*

Playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost    
  tasks:
   - k8s_info:    
       kubeconfig: '~/.kube/config'
       kind: pod
     register: pod_list
```

Comment: Please ensure you are adding aks (.kube) details in user home directory under .kube/config and run the playbook

Comment: @NatarajMedayhal Thank you. I have fixed the issue with your inputs provided in another thread. If I may ask, how can we manage multiple kubeconfig files with Ansible.